# How is the returned pointer from new/malloc kept in scope when the new/malloc function is exited?

Tags: c++, pointers

Is some kind of shared pointer created?

This is an XY question.  My ultimate purpose is to declare a `private` variable in my class that is a pointer, but allocate and populate an array in a `public` function and return the pointer to the `private` variable.  How can I legitimately keep the variable allocated in the function in scope and not just leave it in some quasi-state.  Does the code below actually pass the memory allocated in the function off to the pointer receiving the returned value or is the memory just left hanging?  Does the final call to `delete` in `main()` actually de-allocate the memory pointed to by `returned_data` as if the memory itself had been allocated using this statement: `returned_data = new char [15]`?

In the end, I really need to extend this to a two dimensional pointer like `char **`.  I know that the compiler needs to somehow be notified about at least one of the dimensions of the array, so this may be out of the question.

```
class MyClass
{
    private:
        char *returned_data;
    public:
        char *fetch_data();
};

MyClass::fetch_data()
{
    char *data_pointer;

    data_pointer = new char [15];

    strcpy(data_pointer, "Hello_World!");

    return data_pointer;
};

main()
{
    MyClass ClassName;

    ClassName.returned_data = ClassName.fetch_data();

    // Do whatever

    delete [] ClassName.returned_data;
};
```

I'm just getting back up to speed on my programming having been out of it for a number of years, so there may be imperfections in the code.  This gives the general idea.  It is not the actual code that I am using because that code is mingled in with other code in my application.  Any corrections/suggestions are welcome.

Comment: Why not just use `std::string` for holding string values? Then if you need "many" strings, `std::vector<std::string>` would be a good choice to start with.

Comment: How is *any* local variable returned from a function kept in scope?

Comment: ... and how are you calling a member function ith no object reference?

Comment: The returned pointer from `new` (or `malloc`) is **not** kept in any scope. It's just returned by value. You are responsible for freeing **the memory it points to** with the corresponding function later manually.

Comment: "Scope" applies to *names*, not objects or values.

Comment: BTW: If you know your question is an **XY question**, then you know* that you are posing the **wrong question**. So why not ask the right one?

Comment: @KeithThompson: It also applies to automatic objects, whose lifetime is bound to the scope of their names. (But not to dynamic objects, of course.)

Comment: "how are you calling a member function..."  Sorry, let me fix that.......How's that?

Comment: "BTW; If you know your question is an XY question..."  It was all about approach so that you would know which direction I was thinking.

Comment: @MikeSeymour: No, scope and lifetime are two different things. Scope is a region of program text in which a name is visible. Lifetime is a duration of execution time during which an object exists. They happen to be closely connected for automatic objects if you correlate lines of code to runtime execution, but they're still quite distinct concepts.

Comment: @KeithThompson: OK, looks like we took "apply" to mean slightly different things. Not worth arguing about.

Comment: That still looks incorrect.  I can't access the `private` variable from `main()` can I?

Comment: I think that I would need to make `char *returned_data` into a `public` variable, but you get the idea.......  Thanks for all of the responses.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> Is some kind of shared pointer created?

No, just a pointer. It's returned from the function by copying it, giving another pointer with the same value, i.e. pointing to the same thing.

> How can I legitimately keep the variable allocated in the function in scope and not just leave it in some quasi-state

It's not "allocated in the function"; it was allocated from the free store, and remains until it's explicitly deallocated with `delete`. Just return the pointer. The allocated array doesn't care which pointers point to it, and doesn't change state if they are copied or destroyed.

> Does the code below actually pass the memory allocated in the function off to the pointer receiving the returned value or is the memory just left hanging?

It returns a pointer to that memory, which you can use to access and deallocate the memory. It's not "left hanging" as long as you've got a pointer to it.

> Does the final call to delete in `main()` actually de-allocate the memory pointed to by returned_data as if the memory itself had been allocated using this statement: `returned_data = new char [15]`?

Yes. The returned pointer has the same value (and so points to the same memory) as the result of `new`, so it (or any other pointer with that value) can be used to delete it.

But you don't want to be juggling pointers without a good reason - you're likely to make a mistake, causing memory leaks and worse. Use smart pointers, or containers like `std::vector` and `std::string`, to manage dynamic memory more conveniently.

Comment: Thanks.  That makes sense.  I'll look into the `std::vector` and `std::string`.  As I noted, I'm still getting back up to speed on these things.